# Problem with recoding value ranges with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, spss

I'm trying to translate some code from SPSS to R. 
For the following code block in SPSS...

`RECODE examplevar (1 thru 1.499=1) (1.50 thru 2.499=2) (2.50 thru 3.499=3) (3.50 thru 4.499=4) (4.50 thru 5.499=5) (5.50 thru 6.499=6) (6.50 thru 7=7)
    INTO  newexamplevar.
EXECUTE.`

... I'm trying to use dplyr to do the same recoding of value ranges. This is my code in R:

```
  my_dataset %<>%
  mutate(newexamplevar=case_when(
    my_dataset$examplevar >= 1 & my_dataset$examplevar <= 1.499 ~ 1,
    my_dataset$examplevar >= 1.50 & my_dataset$examplevar <= 2.499 ~ 2,
    my_dataset$examplevar >= 2.50 & my_dataset$examplevar <= 3.499 ~ 3,
    my_dataset$examplevar >= 3.50 & my_dataset$examplevar <= 4.499 ~ 4,
    my_dataset$examplevar >= 4.50 & my_dataset$examplevar <= 5.499 ~ 5,
    my_dataset$examplevar >= 5.50 & my_dataset$examplevar <= 6.499 ~ 6,
    my_dataset$examplevar >= 6.50 & my_dataset$examplevar <= 7 ~ 7
  ))
```

For some reason, the recoding doesn't work right. The frequency tables show that I get the right frequency values but in the wrong order. When I compare the datasets in R and SPSS, I see that e.g. the category '3' in R is the category '5' in SPSS. Obviously, the recoding is wrong (though no warning is issued). 
Does someone have an idea where the mistake could be? It's probably trivial but I do not see what's the issue here.

Comment: Try using `examplevar` in place of `my_dataset$examplevar`

Comment: hi @Shinobi_Atobe, unfortunately it doesn't do anything for me. but good to know i can leave out the dataset name in the future.

Comment: In R base, try running `my_dataset$newexamplevar = round(my_dataset$examplevar)` or `ifelse(my_dataset$examplevar >=1 & my_dataset$examplevar<= 7, round(my_dataset$examplevar), my_dataset$examplevar)` if you have values outside [1;7] that you do not want to modify

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for the replies!
I solved the issue by removing everything from my environment, reloading the dataset and running every single line from a clean slate. Turns out, my code was perfectly fine but the data I was applying it to was dirty. Sometimes the solution is simpler than one could think. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a use-case for `findInterval` or `cut`. Try

```
findInterval(my_dataset$examplevar, c(1, seq(1.5, 6.5, 1)))
```

Consider for example,

```
set.seed(1223)
numb <- runif(10, 1, 7)
numb
#[1] 4.7738 1.7605 2.9715 2.7135 2.1478 6.0351 1.9393 5.3936 6.0228 1.6113

findInterval(numb, c(1, seq(1.5, 6.5, 1)))
#[1] 5 2 3 3 2 6 2 5 6 2
```

---

Similarly with `cut` which will return `factors` instead of integers.

```
cut(numb,breaks = c(1, seq(1.5, 6.5, 1), Inf), labels = 1:7, right = FALSE)
```